# I am creating a online boarding house locator with google maps. But how can I put directions or shortest path from 1 point to another.

Tags: codeigniter, google-maps, google-directions-api

Since I am creating a boarding house locator. I need to put a google map into the page of the owner of the boarding house so they can plot where their boarding house is. And also I need to put routes in my google map from the specific boarding house into a specific location. I need help please.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried this. I found it in the internet. 

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var map_options = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(13.630279, 123.185477),
          zoom: 18,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>

Comment: There's a syntax error on that JS. Try this; <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script><script> function initialize() { var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas'); var map_options = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(13.630279, 123.185477), zoom: 18, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }; var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options) } google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); </script> <div id="map_canvas"></div>, but you'll also need to set a width and height on the #map_canvas div. I just tested it, and I got the map showing up.

Comment: It was working for me.. But my problem is how can I get the direction from 1 point to another.

Comment: Have you read the Google Maps API documentation? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/